# "set subtraction"

Tags: excel, subtraction

I have three Excel files (actually, csv files, so if you have a solution without Excel that's also great).
Each file is a list of email addresses.

I want to extract all the emails from file1 that don't appear in files 2 and 3.
meaning: (file1-file2)-file3

The only thing I could think of is, the very icky solution of: joining all the files, counting how many times each email appears (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP001127779.aspx), 
and then filter out all the emails with more then 1 in the count (or that are not from file1).

Has anyone a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a LOOKUP in file1 to search for entries (a) present in file2 and (b) present in file3. Keep those not found.

Answer (score 0):

Given the common lines are exact matches, I would combine file2 and file3 into say file23

Then, you can use grep:

```
grep -vf file23 file1 > file0
```

file0 will have all lines in file1 that do not exist in file23